# How to use UNION ALL in GeoServer CQL Filter?

Tags: geoserver, cql-filter

Basically I want to combine 2 cql filters of the same layer and output the result on my geoserver layer. It is similar to this SQl query (my case using PostgreSQL):

```
select * from table1 where val = 'a'
union all  // union all means keeps duplicate
select * from table1 where val = 'b'
```

I tried using the cql_filter as below but didnt work

```
cql_filter="val"='a' union "val"='b'
```

I dont find the cql_filter union function (not union of geometries) in https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html as well. What is the proper way to use UNION ALL likewise the SQL query in GeoServer cql filter?

Comment: Could it be done in PostGIS first, then query off of the view of the union?

Comment: @DPSSpatial does that mean I have to create another layer? I prefer to just use the initial layer and filter the features

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you're querying the same layer twice and trying to UNION both results versus multiple WHERE on the layer once?

Comment: @DPSSpatial yeah I didnt realize that simple OR can be used for this case

Comment: Excellent!! Glad that will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine two filters using `or` (or `and`) so your query becomes

```
cql_filter="val"='a' or "val"='b'
```

Comment: that would work (and probably be quicker) in Postgis too

Comment: Clever, I over-complicated things and didn't realize that single OR can be used instead of combining 2 filters / queries

Answer (score 2):

Below solution works but probably not the best.

I made a layer group by combining multiple of same layer instead of just 1 layer

```
(ns:myLayer)(ns:myLayer)
```

Then use the cql filter as below

```
cql_filter="val"='a';"val"='b'
```

Here's the complete URL sample

```
http://localhost/geoserver/visualization/ows?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeNames=(ns:myLayer)(ns:myLayer)&outputFormat=text/javascript&format_options=callback:loadFeatures&srsname=EPSG:3857&cql_filter="val"='a';"val"='b'
```