# Error filtering WFS data using cql_filter

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, cql-filter

I use cql_filter to find input values but an error occurs:

`Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?xml vers"... is not valid JSON`

This is error message in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport
version="1.2.0"
xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc 
http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">
<ServiceException>
  Could not parse CQL filter list.
Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: &quot;\u1ead&quot; (7853), after : &quot;&quot; Parsing : quanhuyen=Qu?n G� V?p;xaphuong=Ph??ng 1;shthua=1;shbando=9.
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

And this is URL for fetched:

```
http://localhost:8081/geoserver/vietnam/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=vietnam%3Ahtgovap&cql_filter=quanhuyen='+quanGet+';xaphuong='+phuongGet+';shthua='+sothuaGet+';shbando='+sotoGet+'&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&q=
```

Here is the code I use `sql_filter`:

```
        var sothuaMap = document.getElementById('sothuaMap');
        var sotoMap = document.getElementById('sotoMap');
        var phuongMap = document.getElementById('phuongMap');
        var quanMap = document.getElementById('quanMap');
        var resultSpan = document.getElementById('span');
        var searchButton = document.getElementById('search');

        function searching(sothuaGet, sotoGet, phuongGet, quanGet) {
        resultSpan.innerHTML = 'Đang tìm thông tin...';
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/geoserver/vietnam/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=vietnam%3Ahtgovap&cql_filter=quanhuyen='+quanGet+';xaphuong='+phuongGet+';shthua='+sothuaGet+';shbando='+sotoGet+'&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&q='  + quanGet +  phuongGet + sothuaGet + sotoGet)
          .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(function (json) {
            var results = json.features;
            ....
```

I have looked and consulted many related questions and issues but none seem to be suitable for my problem.

Comment: You have an XML document returned and are trying to parse it as JSON. Look at the error message in the XML and add that to your question along with the full URL being feteched

Comment: @IanTurton I'm updated my question. Please reopen my question. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message seems clear enough:

```
<ServiceException>
  Could not parse CQL filter list.
Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: &quot;\u1ead&quot; (7853), after : &quot;&quot; Parsing : quanhuyen=Qu?n G� V?p;xaphuong=Ph??ng 1;shthua=1;shbando=9.
</ServiceException>
```

Basically, `quanhuyen=Qu?n G� V?p;xaphuong=Ph??ng 1;shthua=1;shbando=9.` is not a valid string. The most likely issue is that you need
to URL encode your query strings before you send them to GeoServer.

It is also not a valid CQL query if you want to combine the 4 queries then you need to use AND or OR (as explained in [How to use UNION ALL in GeoServer CQL Filter?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/367875/how-to-use-union-all-in-geoserver-cql-filter))

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Saw this error as a result of a data input error. User had input a datetime with 0222 as the year, not 2022. As a result the interpreted datetime value was truncated (the leading zero was removed) so was 13 characters, not 14. When trying to interpret the time portion, 359590 was used, instead of 235959 (must have used an offset to calculate). Amending the year to 2022 resolved the problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/239463)